# make autonomous in laravel

Tags: laravel, transactions

Is it possible create autonomous transaction in laravel? In other words make function which commits even in that case if parent(parent function where this function was called) transaction rollbacks.

Comment: Please provide a concrete example of what you'd like to use this for.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a synchronous language so I don't think this can be done, although what I would do is move the code inside the transactions into an 'Event' and fire it within the parent function.

You can then run the event through an event manager such as Beanstalkd and this function would then run independently of whether the parent function fails!

Answer (score 0):

I successfully did it but I am open for suggestions for a more clean approach.

First you need to duplicate your database connection definition (i.e. "mysql") in your config/database.php and give the duplicate a unique name like "mysql_".

Then you can do this:

```
$connectionName = 'mysql_';
\DB::connection($connectionName)->beginTransaction();

$user = User::on($connectionName)->lockForUpdate()->find(1);
$user->something = 'somethingelse';

if ($user->save() === false) {
    \DB::connection($connectionName)->rollBack();
    throw new Exception('Had to roll back user update');
}

\DB::connection($connectionName)->commit();
```

Last tested in Laravel 9 and PHP 8.0 on a MariaDB.

Might not work in every environment. You need be allowed to open additional database connections.

**Edit:**
Instead of duplicationg your connection definition you can do something like this:

```
// generate a unique connection name
$connectionName = \DB::getName() . '_' . \Ramsey\Uuid\Guid\Guid::uuid7()->toString();

// copy the config of the current connection on the fly
config(['database.connections.' . $connectionName => config('database.connections.' . \DB::getName())]);

// do your stuff with the connection
...

// clean up
config(['database.connections.' . $connectionName => null]);
```